# why I see only COMMIT or commit in SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST - No SQL statement

Tags: mysql, galera, mariadb-10.1

I see in lots of output from `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` only `COMMIT` or `commit` (lowercase and upercase mix). 
What are those transactions? Why no SQL statement? We are running MariaDB 10.1.x and Galera replication (3 nodes).

How to intepret those transactions?

```
> select COMMAND,TIME,STATE,INFO,TIME_MS,STAGE,MAX_STAGE,PROGRESS,MEMORY_USED,EXAMINED_ROWS,QUERY_ID,INFO_BINARY,TID from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where INFO like '%commit%';
+---------+------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| COMMAND | TIME | STATE                | INFO                                                                                                                                                                              | TIME_MS    | STAGE | MAX_STAGE | PROGRESS | MEMORY_USED | EXAMINED_ROWS | QUERY_ID  | INFO_BINARY                                                                                                                                                                       | TID   |
+---------+------+----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+-----------+----------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Query   |    1 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            |   1267.015 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483610134 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 12241 |
| Query   |  112 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 112442.763 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483594429 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 12003 |
| Query   |  151 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 151914.251 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483588122 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 11972 |
| Query   |  156 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 156962.716 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |      141368 |             0 | 483587455 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 11962 |
| Query   |  156 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 156961.757 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |      141368 |             0 | 483587456 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 11960 |
| Query   |  182 | init                 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            | 182230.206 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483584325 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            | 11801 |
| Query   |  229 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 229144.061 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483578193 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 11529 |
| Query   |    0 | Filling schema table | select COMMAND,TIME,STATE,INFO,TIME_MS,STAGE,MAX_STAGE,PROGRESS,MEMORY_USED,EXAMINED_ROWS,QUERY_ID,INFO_BINARY,TID from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where INFO like '%commit%' |      0.346 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |      104808 |             0 | 483610236 | select COMMAND,TIME,STATE,INFO,TIME_MS,STAGE,MAX_STAGE,PROGRESS,MEMORY_USED,EXAMINED_ROWS,QUERY_ID,INFO_BINARY,TID from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where INFO like '%commit%' | 11359 |
| Query   |   66 | init                 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            |  66835.790 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483601099 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            | 10917 |
| Query   |  353 | init                 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            | 353104.108 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |       67544 |             0 | 483561401 | commit                                                                                                                                                                            | 10807 |
| Query   |  494 | init                 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            | 494696.772 |     0 |         0 |    0.000 |      338232 |             0 | 483540392 | COMMIT                                                                                                                                                                            |  9997 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data has been written/updated during an explicit transaction, it may not get written to the data files at all until the final `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement when it is copied from the log file. This makes rolling back after an error, an explicit `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` statement, on restart after a server crash, a very fast operation as it just has to mark the relevant log entries as invalid.

If a lot of data is added or altered during that transaction this may take some time.

> Why no SQL statement?

In this instance `COMMIT TRANSACTION`, or some valid abbreviation, *is* the current SQL statement for those sessions.

Answer (score 2):

Some transactions need to finish up things during the `COMMIT`.  I think that is what you are seeing.

However, 494 seconds is a loooong time!  Even 121s is long.  Look at your code and find the SQL statements for a likely transaction.  Present the SQL here; maybe we can explain things further.

Comment: what are example tasks of "need to finish up things during the"? What he does exactly?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov - Let's see your transaction so we can point at things.